# Wordpress: prevent single view for specific categorie

Tags: wordpress, hook

I wanna know if there´s a possibility to "unlink" image, title and hide the "more link", that the user won´t get the possiblity to go to single view of an article...i wanna know if it´s possible to do that only with a hook within the function.php. I bought a theme and i know wordpress but i don´t wanna touch the sourcecode and the template files, only wanna include an function at the end of functions.php...something like, if the artcile is in an specific category then please don´t link to single view...anyone can help me with this??

thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do (even though it's not a `functions.php` solution):

1. Copy your existing `category.php` file
2. Rename it to `category-#.php`, where # = the id of the category you want to modify
3. Edit your new category file, removing `the_permalink()` wherever it appears

When WordPress serves your custom category, it will use this category template instead of the default one, and you won't mess up the rest of the theme.

Comment: this solution will work for normal templates, but the folder structure in this case is not the normal..i will check out the source code and do the changes inside the theme...i will only have to be careful with an update....thx anyway